# ValueChange Event Slider Control - WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, slider

I have an Application which uses a Slider to show the progress of a video Clip so Its being updated continue-sly through Code to keep it matched with the progress of Video within MediaElement.

I want it(Slider) to not to raise ValueChanged Event (When its values Changes through Code) as I have to handle the ValueChange event only on the User Slide Input.

Can Anybody Help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ManipulationCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Event for this.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there no as much event to fire when `MediaElement` value changes.

For this purpose, people use the `Slider` control attached with the `MediaElement`.

Slider control has the event called `ValueChanged` which is fired, whenever there is change in the position by the user.

By the Slider bar value you can set the MediaElement position like ex.

```
    int SliderValue = (int)timelineSlider.Value;
             TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, SliderValue);
myMediaElement.Position = ts;
```

You can find the example for you problem in [this link of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx), in this link please refer the example given along with the .xaml code and source code.

Comment: I tried to explain my question well but i think there is some misunderstanding. Anway I have a timer which updates the position of slider according to mediaElement to do this i have to set the value of slider like while(playing){ slider.value = mediaElement.Position;} this thing fires event of ValueChanged i just wanted to avoid it. This is what I actually Want. If you have anything to say. Thanks